# How to add class to element if inner value changes on ajax request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to write a piece of code which requests some cryptocurrency prices by ajax, it will request a FIAT currency price as well.
So, I want to add "increased" class when the price goes up & "decreased" class when the price goes down. The script runs every 3 seconds to check the new prices.

I've tried to define a variable on the innerHTML of the price element, and an if/else on what should the script do when the price changes. Here is a sample code:

```
var btn = document.querySelector("#refreshprice");
var price = document.querySelector("#price-text");
var btcirr = document.querySelector("#btcirrrealtime");
var currency_symbol  = document.querySelector("#currency-symbol");
var usdirrinner = usdirr.innerHTML;
var priceinner = price.innerHTML;

window.onload = function(){
    var USDIRR = getUSDIRRRequest();
    USDIRR.send();
    var XHR = getXHRRequest();
    XHR.send();
    var BTCIRR = realtimeirr();
};

setInterval(function(){
    var USDIRR = getUSDIRRRequest();
    USDIRR.send(); 
    var XHR = getXHRRequest();
    XHR.send();
    var BTCIRR = realtimeirr();
},3000);

function getUSDIRRRequest(){
    var USDIRR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    USDIRR.open("GET","http://call2.tgju.org/ajax.json");
    USDIRR.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(USDIRR.readyState == 4 && USDIRR.status == 200){
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(USDIRR.responseText);
            dollarrealtimeprice = parsedData.current.price_dollar_realtime.p.replace(",", "");
            var dollarrealtimepricetoman = dollarrealtimeprice/10;
            usdirr.innerHTML = dollarrealtimepricetoman;
            if(usdirrinner >= dollarrealtimepricetoman){
                usdirr.classList.add("increased");
            }
            else {
                usdirr.classList.add("decreased");
            }
        }
    }
    return USDIRR;
}

function getXHRRequest(){
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.open("GET","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json");
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200){
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            price.innerHTML = parseFloat(parsedData.bpi.USD.rate_float).toFixed(2);
            if(priceinner >= parseFloat(parsedData.bpi.USD.rate_float).toFixed(2)){
                price.classList.add("increased");
            }
            else {
                price.classList.add("decreased");
            }
            currency_symbol.innerHTML = parsedData.bpi.USD.symbol;
        }
    }
    return XHR;
}
```

It was expected to change the class to "increased" when the price goes up. but it just remains decreased.

Comment: Check priceinner and parseFloat(parsedData.bpi.USD.rate_float).toFixed(2) by console logging them. There must be something with the decimal point.

Comment: @Dejvid It should do the maths even if there are one thousand decimals, I think so. Am I wrong?

Comment: It does the maths. But, what if the numbers being used are wrong? You should check if the decimal point is on the correct position. For example, there is a huge difference to 1,00000 and 10000,0. Also, make sure priceinner does not contain dollar sign($) or any other symbol which can confuse the computer.